# Can we get a site name change implemented?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

*Ironic note: The question I'm referencing did not show up in the "Questions that may already have your answer" drop down menu while I was writing this.*

I looked back on [this question](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/options-for-the-name-of-this-site) a couple of minutes ago and noticed that while the answer to change the name to "History of Science and Mathematics" has a net score of 20 (+21, -1), far more than any of the others, we haven't seen anything come of it. I suppose the same goes to some extent for [this question](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/who-should-our-moderators-be), as well as [this one](https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/what-should-we-name-our-chatroom?rq=1), but I'll focus on the name for now.

The question is over one month old, and it seemed that the community's decision was to go with "History of Science and Mathematics". This is as clear cut as it gets for most meta discussions.

Is there any way we can get the name change sometime soon? Has there been any high-level discussion about this in the upper echelons of Stack Exchange? I'd appreciate an answer from a community mod regarding any decisions there for or against the change.

---

I took a leap and posted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244652/how-can-we-get-community-mods-to-address-meta-issues-for-a-beta-site-if-we-have) (really an announcement) on the mother meta.

Comment: I suspect you'll need to make a [meta-tag:feature-request] if you want to change the name. Chances are high that no one with the ability to change our name has seen that post.

Comment: @LoganMaingi Thanks. If the change hasn't happened because of a single tag (or lack thereof). . . oy.

Comment: On that subject (more or less): i flagged the "who should our moderators be" question for it to be made "featured" (as it is supposed to be [the case](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)) on November the 14th and my flag is still unanswered... which makes me think that indeed no one with moderator privileges (ie in our case, I guess, community managers) have been around recently.

Comment: Hence my follow-up comment: maybe it is more urgent to have moderators pro tempore selected, so that they could do this kind of work (handling moderator flags, changing the site name, the chat room name, etc.)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This is definitely something that we can look at. Actually, I remember talking about this before, when this site was in the proposal phase, though I don't recall the details. However, as plannapus suggested, getting pro tems in place is my priority here, and that should be happening soon (as in next few days, not 6-8 weeks).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This site should be named "History of Science and Mathematics" by this afternoon! Sorry it took so long to roll out. There are various reasons for the delay, none of which are very good and all of which are our fault.

I'll leave you to ponder a comment about what could have been, from one of the devs when I confirmed the name change:

> Are you sure they don't want "Historia Philosophiae Naturalis et Mathematicae"?

Comment: Hah... that's actually a pretty nice name. If it weren't for the terrible find-ability that would bring with it.